# Jaspersoft REST API folder traversing, XML PDF extraction

Tags: rest, url, jasperserver

Currently trying to extract an XML document that returns all the files in a particular folder, after which I can return the XML document containing files in a given folder. In the below JPG, I want to extract files from folder **'02_17_2018'**, which is a sub-folder under **'/LatestJLIPDFs'** using the Jaspersoft REST API (see image below).

[image: Jaspersoft Dashboard folders]

Basically, I'm trying to match the query `http://(host):(port)/jasperserver[-pro]/rest_v2/resources?(parameters)` with the Jaspersoft REST API to get to the '02_17_2018'. I've tried several different parameters, none of which seem to work. Here is a list of attempted parameters,

- folderURI=/LatestJLIPDFs/02_17_2018&type=file
- folderURI=/02_17_2018&type=file
- folderURI=/LatestJLIPDFs&type=file&q=02_17_2018
- folderURI=LatestJLIPDFs/02_17_2018&type=folder&q=02_17_2018

among many more attempts. Any hints to how the files in '02_17_2018' can be extracted?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to parameter name **folderURI**. In the documentation, it looks like **folderUri**.
Let's try to write it in camel case as in my example:

```
http://localhost:8080/jasperserver-pro/rest_v2/resources?folderUri=/public&type=file&recursive=false
```